# HTML5 Video PlaybackRate doesn't work in Android chrome with HLS, works with simple http progressive download

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

HTML5 Video PlaybackRate ( > 1) doesn't work with HLS (m3u8), However its working fine with simple Http progressive download, in Android chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [video.js](https://videojs.com/) player library, try using:

`videojs.options.hls.overrideNative = true;`

See also: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/1157

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the Android MediaPlayer to play HLS streams which does not support playbackRate.

The last response from the Chromium team is that there are no plans to change this in the near future:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263654#c78